# Keyboard shortcut to turn off automatic highlighting in preview?

Tags: preview, shortcut

In Preview you can turn on or off automatic highlight/underline/strikeout by clicking the 'pen' in the "highlight" item in the tool bar. The keyboard shortcut for this is <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd><kbd>^ Control</kbd> <kbd>H</kbd>/<kbd>U</kbd>/<kbd>S</kbd>, typed when nothing is selected.

What is the keyboard shortcut to turn ***off*** automatic highlight/underline/strikeout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To turn it off, you have to go back to "text selection mode" but unfortunately, there's no keyboard short cut.   From the *Tools* menu, you would click on Text Selection to get out of the automatic highlight/underline/strikeout mode.

[image]

However, we can create one!

In *System Preferences → Keyboard → App Shortcuts* create a new shortcut by clicking the "+".  Then, in the drop down, select "Preview" for the App, type the **exact** name of the menu title, in this case "Text Selection" and assign it a shortcut.  I used <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd><kbd>^ Control</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> to stay consistent with the other shortcuts.

[image]

Comment: Brilliant -- I had not noticed that going into auto mode turns off text selection mode, and vice versa.  Yes, this works great - thank you!

Comment: If it worked, please don't forget to up vote and/or mark solved!  I'm glad I can help out!

Comment: You can delete comments...but on/off the record, either way is cool - this is our model to further engagement on the site.  Points are nice and it is fun to earn them, but I actually enjoy solving the problems more.